# how to change setIndeterminate jProgressbar in other frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jprogressbar

i have a two frame, frameA and frameB, in frameA i add one button with name buttonA to show frameB and progressbar (setIndeterminate(false)), in frameB i add one button with name buttonB , i want to when i click buttonB, progressbar in frameA.setindeterminate(true)

in frameA

```
frameB b;

public frameA() {
   initComponents();
   progressbar.setIndeterminate(false);
   b = new frameB();
}

public JProgressBar getProgressbar() {
   return progressbar;
}

private void buttonAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                       
    b.setVisible(true);
}
```

in frameB
i use this code in event buttonB clicked

```
private void buttonBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    frameA a= new frameA();
    a.getProgressbar().setIndeterminate(true);
}
```

but it doesnt worked

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

This...

```
private void buttonBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    frameA a= new frameA();
    a.getProgressbar().setIndeterminate(true);
}
```

Isn't going to work, you've just created another instance of `frameA` that's not visible.  It has no relationship to the frame that is currently open.

There are any number of ways you could achieve this...

**You could...**

Pass a reference of `frameA` to `frameB` as part of the constructor call for `frameB`.  Then in you `actionPerformed` method, you would simply use this reference to change the progress bar state.

But this would create a tight coupling between `frameA` and `frameB` which would greatly reduce the re-use of `frameB`

**You could...**

Provide a means by which an interested party could attach an `ActionListener` to `frameB` which would be triggered when the button is clicked.

This assumes a work flow and exposes components to outside sources (via the `ActionEvent#getSource`), which could allow people to change your component...

**You probably should...**

Fire a `PropertyChanged` event.

This is probably the easiest and safest of all the options I've come up with.  Using a property change listener in this manner means you don't need to expose the `JProgressBar`, the `JButton` or produce a tight link between the two frames.

Property change support is built in to `Container` so all components/controls have it.

For example, you would attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to `b` when you construct it.

```
b = new frameB();
b.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progressState")) {
            progressbar.setIndeterminate((Boolean)evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
});
```

Add in `bFrame`'s `actionPerformed` method, you would simple call...

```
firePropertyChange("progressState", false, true);
```

When you want to set the indeterminate state (you could swap the `boolean` values to reset it if you wanted to)

Comment: Yee, been watching that for a while :D - it's been sitting on 49, 999 :P

Comment: and probably the time to change avatar too:-)

Comment: please [see very interesting post about most of us (one post is about links to tutorial, next answer with an SSCCE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175148/are-we-an-answer-factory), ignore that this forum is very offensive with various answers with full of nonsense by ...., simple I hate this forum